# Laravel 5 Unit Test - Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, eloquent, phpunit

I tried creating a unit test for the relationships between my `User` and `Shop` models, however when I run `vendor\\bin\\phpunit` this error(s) are thrown, I have no idea about this since I'm a newbie in unit testing. I tried to run my code on my controller to see if the relationship actually works, and fortunately it is working as expected, but not when run in phpunit. What have I done wrong for this phpunit not to work with Models?

> **`Fatal error:`** *`Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in E:\projects\try\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1013`*
>
> **`Stack trace:`**
> *`E:\projects\try\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(979): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection(NULL)`*

This is my UserTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

use App\User;
use App\Shop;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{

    protected $user, $shop;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->setUp();
    }
    
    function setUp()
    {
        $user = new User([
            'id' => 1,
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Doe',
            'email' => 'JohnDoe@example.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'facebook_id' => null,
            'type' => 'customer',
            'confirmation_code' => null,
            'newsletter_subscription' => 0,
            'last_online' => null,
            'telephone' => null,
            'mobile' => null,
            'social_security_id' => null,
            'address_1' => null,
            'address_2' => null,
            'city' => null,
            'zip_code' => null,
            'signed_agreement' => 0,
            'is_email_confirmed' => 0
        ]);

        $user = User::find(1);
        $shop = new Shop([
            'id' => 1,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'name' => 'PureFoods Hotdog2',
            'description' => 'Something that describes this shop',
            'url' => null,
            'currency' => 'USD'
        ]);
        $user->shops()->save($shop);

        $shop = new Shop([
            'id' => 2,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'name' => 'PureFoods Hotdog',
            'description' => 'Something that describes this shop',
            'url' => null,
            'currency' => 'USD'
        ]);

        $user->shops()->save($shop);

        $this->user = $user;

    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_user_has_an_id(){
        $user =  User::find(1);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $user->id);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_user_has_a_first_name()
    {
        $this->assertEquals("John", $this->user->first_name);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function a_user_can_own_multiple_shops()
    {
        $shops = User::find(1)->shops()->get();
        var_dump($this->shops);
        $this->assertCount(2, $shops);
    }
}
```

It seems, this error is caused by this line of code:
`$user->shops()->save($shop);` - this code actually works when run in my sample routes or Controller but is throwing `errors` when run in `phpunit`

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guarded = [ 'id' ];
    protected $table = "users";   

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    /**
     * returns the Shops that this user owned
     */
    public function shops()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Shop');
    }
}
```

**Shop.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Shop extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [ 'id' ];
    protected $table = "shops";

    /**
     * returns the Owner of this Shop
     */
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Any help will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First of all, **`setUp()`** is called before every test, so you shouldn't call it from within the constructor

Second of all, you should call the **`parent::setUp()`** in your **`setUp()`** to initialize the app instance.

Answer (score 48):

One more reason

check if the test class is extending **use Tests\TestCase;** rather then **use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;**

Laravel ships with the later, but **Tests\TestCase** class take care of setting up the application, otherwise models wont be able to communicate with the database if they are extending **PHPunit\Framework\TestCase**.

Comment: (it says to avoid this type of comments...) BUT THANKS!!!!!!. I HAVE BEEN STUCK WITH THIS FOR 2 WHOLE DAYS!!!!!!!

Comment: But im a bit confused about that, why defaults boilerplate use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase then? Why would you like to use that insteat of Tests\TestCase?

Comment: for basic tests i don't think you would want to setup the application, which Tests\TestCase does. I think that's the reasoning i am not sure tho. You can ask the laravel team.

Answer (score 14):

**Example:**

```php
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
  private $user;

  public function setUp()
  {
    parent::setUp();

    $this->user = \App\User::first();
  }

   public function testExample()
   {
      $this->assertEquals('victor@castrocontreras.com', $this->user->email);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

a solution

**use PHPunit\Framework\TestCase**

Put this

**use Tests\TestCase**

Comment: Seems duplicate answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60799352/4355179)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the id '2' to both shops.

Assigning is should not be neccessary since I assume the shop table id field is an autoincrement field.

Also look into [database factories in the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database-testing#writing-factories), it will simplify things for you.

Answer (score 1):

That can be happens when you try to read database from dataprovider function. Like me tried, yes. The work way:

```
protected static $tariffs_default;
protected function setUp(): void {
    parent::setUp ();
    if (!static::$tariffs_default){
        static::$tariffs_default = DB::...;
    }
}    
// in dataprovider we use string parm, named as our static vars
public static function provider_prov2(){
    return [
        [".....", [ 'tariffs'=>'tariffs_default'] ],
    ];
}
// then, in test we can ask our data by code:
public function testSome(string $inn, string $ogrn, $resp_body){
    if ( $ta_var = Arr::get( $resp_body, 'tariffs' ) ){
        Arr::set($resp_body, 'tariffs', static::$$ta_var );
    }
    $this->assert...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. this was the reason this happened to me. I was looking very bemused before I found this.

Answer (score 0):

*Cause of the problem*: you can't use Laravel Models functionality from code called in the  constructor of Class UserTest - even though you put the code in the method "setUp", you unnecessarily called it from the constructor. SetUp is called by phpUnit without you needing to do it in the constructor.

When the UserTest constructor has run, the Laravel Bootstrap code has not yet been called.

When the UserTest->setUp() method is called, the Laravel Bootstrap code HAS been run, so you can use you Models etc.

```
class UserTest extends TestCase
{protected $user, $shop;

function __construct()
{
    $this->setUp(); // **THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE**
}

function setUp()
{
    $user = new User([....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `composer dump-autoload`

~Regards