# Call to a member function connection() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-7, laravel-artisan

I am trying to create a new virtual development environment for one of my projects on Github. I have installed MariaDB, PHP 7, made a local clone of the repository, and restored its *.env*-file. It should be working.

Unfortunately, when I type *php artisan* and *composer update*, I receive the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:1058
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1024): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::resolveConnection(NULL)
>   #1 src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(859): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getConnection()
>   #2 src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(818): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newBaseQueryBuilder()
>   #3 src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(802): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->newQueryWithoutScopes()
>   #4 src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1374): Illuminate\Database\Eloquen in src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php on line 1058

I do not know if this is relevant to the error at hand, but note the misspelling of Eloquent on stack trace #4.

You can find my composer.json file over here:
https://github.com/galadhremmin/Parf-Edhellen/blob/master/src/composer.json

PHP version: 7.1.2 on Debian 9.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**Edit** This affects the *artisan* and *composer* components which won't even run.

Comment: Is MariaDB (the MySQL service) actually turned on? Just because you installed it doesn't mean it's on.

Comment: @BrianGottier I believe it is, as it does respond when I type _mysql_ in the terminal. I can log in, and query the database with the credentials provided in the _.env_-file.

Comment: Look at this file: src/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php line number 1058, whatever instance of a class is in front of the connection() method has not been instantiated.

Comment: and of course you've double checked your connection settings at least twice ... so I'd try to connect with a plain PHP script and debug that. I'm just talking about mysqli functions or PDO.

Comment: @BrianGottier The following is successful: `php -r '$i = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "elfdict", "elfdict"); echo !$i ? "fail\n" : "success\n";'`

Comment: Sounds Laravel specific then. I've used Laravel a few times in the past, but not qualified to give you help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 Unit Test - Call to a member function connection() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42512676/laravel-5-4-unit-test-call-to-a-member-function-connection-on-null)

Comment: @Nawin No, it is most certainly not. This affect the artisan CLI, which is completely inoperable.

Comment: @BrianGottier It was! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the root of the issue by using `debug_print_backtrace`. It is an excellent method which prints a full back-trace.

The issue in this case was the fact that I had attached a logging service to the exception handler. The logger would reach out to a database in order to record the error that occurred, and it did *not* support the CLI environment.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.